# What false/true really mean for IPreInsertEventListeners?

Tags: nhibernate, audit

I recently have found out how to audit instances with the `IPreDeleteEventListener`, `IPreInsertEventListener` and `IPreUpdateEventListener` in the `NHibernate.Event` namespace.

However, it still confuses me what shall these event return either on successful or unsuccessful finality.

For example, let's take a look at Ayende's blog article found here:

- [`NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener & IPreInsertEventListener`](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener)

Following his example, one could implement the interfaces as following:

```
public class AuditEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener {
    public bool OnPreInsert(OnPreInsert @event) {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IHaveAuditInformation;
        if (audit == null) return false;

        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedBy", name);

        audit.CreatedAt = time;
        audit.CreatedBy = name;

        return false;
    }
}
```

What odes it actually mean to return either `true` or `false` as return value, since I have another example where `true` is returned instead of `false` as Ayende wrote.

- [`Soft Deletes With NHibernate`](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2013/03/21/soft-deletes-with-nhibernate.aspx)

Which seems to return `true` instead of `false`.

```
public class SoftDeletableListener : IPreDeleteEventListener {
    public void Register(Configuration cfg) {
        cfg.EventListeners.PreDeleteEventListeners = 
            new IPreDeleteEventListener[] { this }
                .Concat(cfg.EventListeners.PreDeleteEventListeners)
                .ToArray();
    }

    public Boolean OnPreDelete(PreDeleteEvent @event) {
        ISoftDeletable softDeletable = @event.Entity as ISoftDeletable;

        if (softDeletable == null) return true;

        EntityEntry entry = @event.Session
            .GetSessionImplementation()
            .PersistenceContext
            .GetEntry(@event.Entity);
        entry.Status = Status.Loaded;

        softDeletable.Deleted = true;

        Object id = @event.Persister
            .GetIdentifier(@event.Entity, @event.Session.EntityMode);
        Object [] fields = @event.Persister
            .GetPropertyValues(@event.Entity, @event.Session.EntityMode);
        Object version = @event.Persister
            .GetVersion(@event.Entity, @event.Session.EntityMode);

        @event.Persister.Update(id
            , fields
            , new Int32[1]
            , false
            , fields
            , version
            , @event.Entity
            , null
            , @event.Session.GetSessionImplementation());

        return true;
    }
}
```

So I wonder, what `false`/`true` actually tells NHibernate depending on the listener dealt with.

Comment: In the `SoftDeletableListener` example, shouldn't be `if (softDeletable == null) return false;` (`false` instead of `true`)? Otherwise no entity will be deleted, whether it's `ISoftDeletable` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned value in this case should be *enum*, Let's use the name `OnPreEventResult`, and these would be the possible values:

- `OnPreEventResult.Continue` => to continue currently return `false`
- `OnPreEventResult.Break` => at the moment, when the **`true`** is returned the *Action* is **aborted**

So, as both examples above show, we can use the return value to manage the execution flow:

1. **to Continue**:
   If we in the `AuditEventListener` return *false*, we in fact return something like `OnPreEventResult.Continue`. We've made some custome logic, and we want NHibernate to continue... so the **false** is returned
2. **to Break/Abort**:
   Ayende's example is showing us how to change the real DELETE into UPDATE. Update is called explicitly  `@event.Persister.Update(...` and the delete is **not** executed due to the returned value **true**, i.e. `OnPreEventResult.Break`

In the code, the returned values are stored in local variable called `veto`, which is again more self descriptive.

See:

- [EntityInsertAction](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Action/EntityInsertAction.cs), or
- [EntityDeleteAction](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Action/EntityDeleteAction.cs)

A snippet from the `EntityInsertAction`, the `Execute()` method:

```
...
bool veto = PreInsert();

if (!veto)
{    
    persister.Insert(id, state, instance, Session);
...
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this great explanation! I now better understand what is going on. These examples, IMHO, would have been much more cleaner code if they would have actually used this `OnPreventResult` enum. Thanks @Radim!

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy NHibernate :)

Comment: Great explanation.
In reality the example is wrong. If the class does not implement "Soft Delete" contract, the interceptor should return false and not true.